# NodeJs variables kind of connected (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I basically want to set my `jsonOut` to my `jsonIn`, which works great til that point, but when I try to set the `jsonOut.Patcher[0].Targets` to `[]`, the `jsonIn` also gets modified and I don't get why it does that.

The `jsonIn` also is a `const`ant, so there should be no way to modify any way. Not to forget to mention, both of the `jsonIn.Patches[0].Targets` and   `jsonOut.Patches[0].Targets` are being cleared out.

[The in.json](https://pastebin.com/zBQ1CkxW)

I already checked if there was any way that the `jsonIn` could ever be set to `jsonOut` anywhere in my code, but i could find anything that could do that.

Maybe the issue is obvious and im just too blind to see it

```js
import fs from "fs";

const jsonIn = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./in.json"), "utf8");
let jsonOut = jsonIn
jsonOut.Patches[0].Targets = []
jsonIn.Patches[0].Targets.forEach((base) => {
    const fileExists = fs.existsSync(`../${base.File}`);
      if (fileExists) {
            console.log(`"[92m${base.File}[0m"`)
            jsonOut.Patches[0].Targets.push(base)
            fs.writeFileSync("./temp.json", JSON.stringify(base));
      } else {
            console.log(`"[31m${base.File}[0m"`)
      }
});
fs.writeFileSync("./out.json", JSON.stringify(jsonOut));
```

Comment: `const` means the reference can't be reassigned, not that *what it references* can't be modified. It sounds like you actually want a *copy* of `jsonIn` which you can modify w/o affecting `jsonIn`.

Comment: when you are setting `let jsonOut = jsonIn` you are coping the pointer. Look into how to [deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy)

Comment: I didnt know, when doing `jsonOut = jsonIn` both are changed when one of them got changed, the deep copy thing fixed it, thanks